# What's the minimum division of drawing in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, drawing, shapes

I've got a question regarding shape drawing in UWP. You create e.g. a `Rectangle` in UWP and add it to a canvas on screen. Let's say we have a rectangle with a small size of 10x5. You add it to the canvas and it displays correctly on the screen. Then you zoom in using standard screen transformations (composite transforms), but you don't change the size of the rectangle (only the scale):

Ok, now we've got a rectangle with a size of 10x5 and a big zoom in (about 50-150). The rectangle width and height accepts `double` values, so let's say I change the size of the rectangle to 10.1x5, but the size of the rectangle doesn't change proportionally.

Here's a recorded gif:[image: Changing width of rectangle]The start width of the rectangle is about 11.704 and I change the width from the right side (using my mouse which isn't visible on the video), so that in the end it has a width of about 4, but generally the rectangle should change it's size linearly. I looked at it inside the debugger and the value which is calculated is really changing (11.704 -> 11.389 -> 10.898 -> ...), but it doesn't change the width on the drawing.

At first it looked like UWP Shapes would cast the width of the element to an `int`, but when I had a look at it inside the debugger it's more like an approximated value (when the width was < 0.6 the shape wasn't visible at all, when > 0.6 it suddenly shown, but it had a width of about 1.2). So my assumption would be that the minimum division when drawing shapes in UWP is minimum 1.2.

Changing the scale without the size is another option, but I'm curious what's behind drawing in UWP. If it's important I've been testing it on a screen resolution of 1920x1080.

Comment: Firstly, what's the relative code about  your "composite transforms" here, how you change the scale? Scale X or Y or both?  Secondly,  "but it doesn't change the width on the drawing." what is this mean? Please provide some relative code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be experiencing layout rounding issues. The canvas containing the rectangle, turn off layout rounding like this:

```
<Canvas UseLayoutRounding="False">
   <Rectangle/>
</Canvas>
```